# Trouble using strings

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner. I don't know why I can't use strings. It says `string does not have a type`.

**main.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "Pancake.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Pancake good;

    good.setName("David");

    cout << good.name << endl;

}
```

**Pancake.h**

```
#ifndef PANCAKE_H
#define PANCAKE_H
#include <string>

class Pancake {
    public:
        void setName( string x );
        string name;
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // PANCAKE_H
```

**Pancake.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pancake.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Pancake::setName( string x ) {
    name = x;
}
```

This only happens when I use strings. When I use a integer and replace `string x` with `int x` in all instances of `string x` it then works. But why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've simply left out the namespace in your header file:

```
#ifndef PANCAKE_H
#define PANCAKE_H
#include <string>

class Pancake {
    public:
        void setName( std::string x );
        std::string name;
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // PANCAKE_H
```

It might be best to avoid `using namespace ...` and instead accept the extra typing with prepending the namespace.

Comment: It works. Thanks, but why do you say not to use `using namespace`?

Comment: To avoid unintentional conflicts; but this is a personal preference and isn't necessary.